# Bootstrap affix not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've built documentation using [Bootstrap doc's CSS and JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). Below is the code of sidebar in my documentation:

```
<div class="col-md-3 docs">
    <div class="bs-docs-sidebar">
        <ul class="nav docs-sidebar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#one">One</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#two">Two</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And below is the jquery code of `.affix`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
    $('.bs-docs-sidebar').affix({ offset: { top: 290 } })
})
```

When I open my page it does not display the sidebar with entries One, Two. When I scroll the page, the sidebar shows "Two" as active but never shows entry "One".

I am using Bootstrap v3.2.0. Why is the sidebar not working properly with `.affix`. I even tried out with `data-spy=affix` but it didn't work.

How do I make sidebar work properly with affix?

Comment: Is it possible to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem *in its entirety* with as little code as possible.  You can create the example in jsFiddle or right in Stack Overflow using snippets.

Answer (score 1):

To add [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix), you just need to do something like this:

```
$(".bs-docs-sidebar").affix({ offset: { top: 60 } });
```

This will dynamically add one of the following classes to your item based on scroll position:

- `.affix-top`
- `.affix`
- `.affix-bottom`

And then set some styling when the .affix class is in place (bootstrap will automatically add `position:fixed` so we just need to set the height:

```
.bs-docs-sidebar.affix {
    top: 20px;
}
```

#### [Here's a working demo in jsFiddle that uses Affix on the BS sidebar](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/v6zhz/170/)

But it sounds like you're actually having issues with scrollspy and the way that bootstrap is styling `.active` items.  Here's a [blog post that goes through all the steps of setting up a side nav bar like the one that twitter bootstrap uses](http://www.codingeverything.com/2014/02/BootstrapDocsSideBar.html). (*Disclaimer, I am the author of that post*).

Comment: I tried both things but still does not work. The sidebar never comes on page load.

Comment: @user3108072, you can take this working example and start backfilling with yours until you notice what's wrong.  Or start from  a clean slate and compare to your existing solution.  Either way, we can't be of much help on the other side of the wire unless we can see the actual code you're having trouble with.  So your best options are to produce a [**working example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the exact issue you're havingor try applying the working example to your solution yourself.